# Having problems with sessions and pages in php

Tags: php, mysql

I really don't understand what I am doing here. I have this page `profesor.php` in which I want to insert some data into the database. After I submit the data from the form I want to be redirected to another page `insert.php` and display a message. 
So I have `profesor.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $fullname = $_SESSION['name'];
    echo "<h1> Welcome " . $fullname . "</h1>"; 
} else {
    $result = "You are not logged in yet";
}

if (isset($_POST['studname'])) {
    include_once("dbConnect.php");

    $studname = strip_tags($_POST['studname']);
    $course = strip_tags($_POST['course']);
    $grade = strip_tags($_POST['grade']);

    $getStudidStm = "SELECT userid FROM users WHERE name = '$studname'";
    $getStudidQuery = mysqli_query($dbCon, $getStudidStm);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($getStudidQuery);
    $studid = $row[0]; 

    $_SESSION['studid'] = $studid;
    $_SESSION['course'] = $course;
    $_SESSION['grade'] = $grade;
    header("Location: insert.php");
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title><?php echo $fullname ;?></title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<h2>Insert new grade</h2>
<form id="insertForm" action="insert.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Student: <input type="text" name="studname" /> <br />
Course : <input type="text" name="course" /> <br />
Grade  : <input type="text" name="grade" /> <br />
<input type="submit" value="Insert" name="Submit" />
</form></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and `insert.php`

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['studid'])) {
    include_once("dbConnect.php");

    $studid = $_SESSION['studid'];
    $course = $_SESSION['course'];
    $grade = $_SESSION['grade'];
    echo $studid;
    echo $course;
    echo $grade;
}
```

My problem is that `insert.php` doesn't display anything. I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Need some help.

Comment: What have you done to troubleshoot this? Seems like you could have done more. Like, are the session variables being carried over to the new page? Are you even sure you're getting that far in the first page?

Comment: inside insert.php under session_start(); write a line: var_dump($_SESSION); this makes it able to see what values are set inside your session, and also IF they are set

Comment: Why do you use `multipart/form-data` if you dont upload anything?

Comment: Well is strange it displays the data that I used first to login. I am working on a profesors/students app and when a profesor logs in he can add a new grade to a student. So I get the data that the profesor used to log in. I am really lost and I don't understand why I get this

Comment: `action="profesor.php"`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your problem is in your form:

```
<form id="insertForm" action="insert.php" [...]
```

you send data to `insert.php` but all the 'magic' with

```
$_SESSION['studid'] = $studid;
$_SESSION['course'] = $course;
$_SESSION['grade'] = $grade;
```

you keep in `profesor.php`

Just change `action="insert.php"` to `action="profesor.php"` and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. It was a stupid mistake. I will accept your answer in 5 minutes.